# How to check if a card is default payment card in Apple Wallet?

Tags: ios, credit-card, wallet, passkit

The problem is on the Apple Wallet's APIs. There's a requirement to check if payment card issue from my application is **default** or not. If it's not then do something to encourage the user to make it a default one. Now, I can't seem to find such API from Apple Wallet's **PassKit**

I've tried checking Apple's API Reference, Googling and Asking in Apple's developer forums. No, real solutions so far.

From the API reference, I found this `PKPaymentPass.PKPaymentPassActivationState` but it only contains activation status, which does not seems to be status of being **default** payment card. Properties of `PKPass` seems to be offering no such values, APIs from `PKPassLibrary` also not.

Is there a way to do this? Or is just impossible?

Comment: Why would your app possibly try to influence the financial decisions of your users?

Comment: Many of the Apple Pay APIs that relate to payment cards are private and only available under NDA.  However, I don't think what you are asking is possible.  You should ask your company's Apple Pay representative.